# How to read last 1000 sectors of hard drive

Tags: data-recovery, disk-encryption, hfs+

Here's the specific issue in short topics I think might be relevant:

1. I have a Western Digital (my book Studio) external drive. (the old version, bought somewhere around 2009 that has both USB and FIREWIRE ports)
2. In that drive I had a load of important backups.
3. The drive was encrypted.
4. Somehow things went wrong during an unplugging of the drive and I lost access.
5. the drive is still good, no bad sectors.
6. I managed to recover the files with various tools and even have a complete image of it made with dd command.
7. The issue is that the recovered files are still encrypted.
8. From the investigation I've done, I've managed to figure out that these WD drives use a hard-coded encryption key that is stored in the last sectors of the drive, and the password I chose when encrypting is just used to create a sha256 hash that in turn is used to access the actual decryption key.
9. From this (very good) writeup about these drives: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1002.pdf I have figured out that for my specific chipset, the encryption key starts with 'SInE' somewhere in the last blocks of the hard drive.
10. My question is how can I read the hard drives blocks in order to grab the complete key? Can dd do this? It's a 2 Tera byte drive, has no bad sectors. According to the writeup posted above, the WD hardware blocks access to thee sectors, but if I take the drive out of the WD case and plug it in directly to a SATA port, I should be able to access them.
11. Things I have tried: because I already have a disk image of the drive for 'safety', I tried recovering the files directly from the drive, but the recovery software, while performing deep scans, also searches for older (deleted) files and seems to recover less stuff. So I wrote zeros to the entire drive using dd (to make sure there would be no recoverable 'deleted' files), then I put the drive back into the original Western Digital case and formatted again, and created the same encrypted drive (with the same password) as I had originally, then used dd to 'restore' the image I had made... Then I ran a mac diskutil first aid (these were all mac files and the original format was HFS+). My hope was that the drive would somehow recognise that the files within were still encrypted. Didn't work.

I have the recovered files on a separate disk, but can't find any software that can decode/repair them. If I try to decode manually, it always tells me the decryption key is wrong. This is because of what I said previously: My password is not the actual key, it's just used to access the hard-coded key on the drive.

DD is terribly slow for 'experimenting' with a 2 Terabyte drive, any test I want to try takes over 32 hours, so I need a way to 'skip' to the last sectors of the drive, except I don't know how many sectors there are or what number I should skip to, or even if DD is the right tool for reading the raw ascii blocks I need.

Any help appreciated, I've been at this for almost 20 days now.

Thank you very much.

P.S. I have both Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) and Mac computers, so I'm looking for a non-windows solution. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`tail -c 512000 /dev/sdX` will read the last 512000 bytes of the drive and write them to stdout.

Pipe to `perl -0777 -ne 'print $& if /SInE.*/s'` to extract the part starting with the first occurrence of `SInE` in there.

Or get `perl` to seek to the end by itself:

```
perl -e '
  seek STDIN, -512000, 2 or die "seek: $!";
  $/ = undef;
  $_ = <STDIN>;
  print $& if /SInE.*/s' < /dev/sdX
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying the first option (tail) as we speak, but it's taking an awful lot of time, as if it's reading the whole drive trying to find the end.... Is this normal? Been running for almost 30 minutes now. I would have imagined it would be 'smart enough' to start from the end and count backwards.

Comment: Is that on Ubuntu? On Debian, `sudo strace -e lseek tail -c 512000 /dev/sda > /dev/null` is instantaneous and shows `lseek(3, -512000, SEEK_END)` being called.

Comment: no, I'm currently trying on the mac, but thanks, if this doesn't work, I'll try in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, `dd skip={Number of 1kB input blocks to skip} bs=1024 if=yourdiskimage of=imageofendofdrive` skips forward by the specified amount of kilobytes in the input.

**But**: your drive image isn't encrypted at all. You're trying to solve something that's not in need of a solution!

As you say yourself:

> Things I have tried: because I already have a disk image of the drive for 'safety', I tried recovering the files directly from the drive, but the recovery software, while performing deep scans, also searches for older (deleted) files and seems to recover less stuff. So I wrote zeros to the entire drive using dd (to make sure there would be no recoverable 'deleted' files), then I put the drive back into the original Western Digital case and formatted again, and created the same encrypted drive (with the same password) as I had originally, then used dd to 'restore' the image I had made... Then I ran a mac diskutil first aid (these were all mac files and the original format was HFS+). My hope was that the drive would somehow recognise that the files within were still encrypted. Didn't work.

The data pertaining existence of files is not encrypted at all, otherwise your recovery software couldn't find *any*  files. The drive doesn't "understand" the file system you're using - it works directly on the bytes you write to disk.

If you can recover files but their contents are actually encrypted, you must have had another layer of encryption on top of that. Something that sits in your filesystem driver layer and encrypts the individual files, not the whole disk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm quite sure it's encrypted, it decrypts automatically when I connect to my mac (from where I ran the recovery software) password is stored in my keychain. About 20% of them were good, 80% didn't decrypt. I assume this happened during the unplugging where everything went wrong... 
In any case, I've exhausted all options to decrypt the files (some are text files, so  easy to see they're encrypted) except trying the hard-coded key that's supposed to be on the drive, hence my question. But if you know another way I can get these files working again, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: the hardware contained inside the WD box decrypts on-the-fly when accessing the drive (through the USB bridge chip). So I assume any software that's trying to access/recover also goes through the same chip and the same process.

Comment: as said, the drive encrypts the whole data, not the contents of files. If you were able to recover 20%, that means what you've read was not encrypted. if 20% of files were recoverable, we can be 100% sure that they were not encrypted.

Comment: according to the technical writeup I posted, "My Passport drives that support HW encryption by the USB bridge (see Table1), the chip uses an AES-128 or AES-256 bit key to encrypt user data before storing it on the HDD", so each file is encrypted using this method.

Comment: "To summarize, given the correct password the correct KEK will be generated and the correct DEK will be decrypted and the LUN with user data is mounted with transparent on-the-fly decryption of data"

Comment: exactly. You were able to recover some of the files, so your drive supplied you with decrypted data. Not with encrypted data. There's no such thing as "a bit encrypted".

Comment: I was able to recover 100% of the data. All the files, folders and filenames are correct and in the right place, but 80% of them are encrypted (at least it seems that way, looking at the text files). Normally in a text file with broken headers or something like that you can still see some 'english' words. In my case they all look lke encrypted blobs, not a single english word to be found, which is what leads me to believe they're encrypted. Of course I may be wrong, but not willing to give up until I grab the key from the last sectors and try to decrypt some of them.

Comment: yes, so to repeat: if the contents of the files are encrypted, then it wasn't the hard drive that did the encryption, as the hard drive doesn't know, care or even understand what a file is. If you can read 100% of the files, the file system itself, i.e. the information which file lies where, was unencrypted. Which definitely says "not a full-disk encryption".

Comment: According to the writeup, it's the USB chip contained within the external hard drive case that does the encryption on the fly when reading/writing to the hard drive. This is not a 'normal' external drive box with just a sata connection, it contains specific Western Digital hardware to handle the encryption. (Of course not the hard drive itself). I don't know if it's done on a per block or per file basis. Even when there's no user password, the external box's hardware still encrypts the data, except it does it with a publicly accessible key (all this info is in the writeup)

Comment: yes, you can repeat that. But it simply still does not apply to you; you have unencrypted filesystem data, which we both agree on, and (probably) encrypted file contents, so this **cannot** be full-disk encryption. There's really no reason for doubt!

Comment: @ProtonSnow the usb chip will be encrypting the full disk. The typical use is to encrypt the disk such that removing it from the usb enclosure destroys the data. It cannot encrypt some files.

Comment: thanks James. I find that somewhat confusing... How does it work exactly?Wouldn't that take an awful lot of time every time I plugged the disk in? it's 2 Terabytes.... I can plug it in and save a single file and unplug it un under 20 seconds... There's no way it has time to decrypt then re-encrypt an entire 2 terabyte disk in that time.

Comment: it encrypts and decrypts exactly the blocks that your computer tries to read on the fly. But: these blocks are the *underlying storage* on top of which your filesystem exists. No notion of "file content" vs "file names", "directory structure", "metadata" there. Just the raw bytes that you read and write to disk.

Comment: Forgive me if I sound repetitive and dumb about this, but then how can it be that all the file names, extensions, folder names etc are correct, but most of the files still don't open and are clearly 'jumbled' up? Are the folder structures and filenames stored in a different location that the actual file contents? (I guarantee there was no other encryption of any kind on these files, just the standard Western Digital out-of-the box encryption that's default to that specific hardware... And in this case, any other suggestions on how I can somehow recover the files?

Comment: @ProtonSnow don't worry, you don't seem dumb! But I've addressed that already: the most likely explanation is that you had another layer of software encryption running on top which works on a per-file basis (or ransomware). No, they are not stored somewhere else, which is exactly why I come to the conclusion that if you can read the file names, then the whole contents of the disk are not disk-encrypted.

Comment: 100% guarantee there was no other layer of encryption, there never has been. Been using the same drive with the same password for over 12 years with no issues, and it's the only encrypted drive I have ever had, never encrypted anything else, that's why I'm baffled at this issue.... And this was a drive where I stored all my projects... Literally 20 years of logo designs, websites etc... I've been telling myself for over a year its time to get a new drive because this drive was getting old... None of the files are 'important' for my current work, but it breaks my heart to lose 20 years of work.

Comment: I feel you, but whatever crushed the contents of your files, it wasn't the disk encryption.